# UILocalNotification my alert fires every minute swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilocalnotification

I need your help. I write code for localNotifications.

```
func scheduleNotification() {
   // Schedule the notification
   let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
   localNotification.fireDate = dueDate
   localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
   localNotification.alertBody = text
   localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        // at first start I write this line [1]
   // localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Second
   localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Weekday
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

In this area [1] at first I write that code with NScalendarUnit.Second and start my app. Alert fires fine, but it doesn't stopping and fires every minute. After that I remove my app from iPhone and paste new line of code with weekday line. I start app and add new alert works fine, but first alert which I created at first start keep firing every minute after fire second alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to cancel the old repeating notification.

You can retrieve the list of current scheduled notifications with [`scheduledLocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/scheduledLocalNotifications), you can then cancel it with [`cancelLocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelLocalNotification:) after appropriate filtering.

Or you can use [`cancelAllLocalNotifications`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelAllLocalNotifications) directly if you don't have any other notifications.